# Using React-Native - Pull to refresh not hiding on iOS, working fine on Android

Tags: ios, react-native, pull-to-refresh

[image]

React-native :

I am using refresh-control for Scrollview, when pull to refresh triggers it won't hide even after data is updated on iOS. Same code works fine on Android.

I have tried debugging but didn't reach anywhere. Loading is being set to false.

```
RefreshControl
                  onRefresh={refetch}
                  refreshing={loading}
                  style={{ backgroundColor: 'transparent' }}
```

Expected - Refresh control should hide.
Actual - Not hiding.

Comment: Please show me the entire code.

Comment: This error is in defining refresh-control. Maybe some sort of padding or content inset. The code is working fine on Android and other iOS devices @hongdevelop

Comment: Did you ever find a fix to this?